# How to trigger dag via rest api in Apache airflow, getting 403 forbidden error

Tags: python, rest, airflow

I tried using the below command

```
curl -X POST  
http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/dag_trigger_external_api/dag_runs
H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"conf":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"}'
```

I have also installed REST_api plugin inside pulgin folder under airflow_home directory and set rbac=True

I have also inserted below lines of code in airflow.config file

Filters out loading messages from the standard out
DEFAULT: True

filter_loading_messages_in_cli_response = True

HTTP Header Name to be used for authenticating REST calls for the REST API Plugin
DEFAULT: 'rest_api_plugin_http_token'

rest_api_plugin_http_token_header_name = rest_api_plugin_http_token

HTTP Token to be used for authenticating REST calls for the REST API Plugin
DEFAULT: None
Comment this out to disable Authentication

rest_api_plugin_expected_http_token = None